# WooCommerce REST API PUT on Variations does not work

Tags: woocommerce-rest-api

I have logged this issue on GitHub but I understand it will take time to get attention. Is there another way of updating Product Variations?

https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/35555

When I PUT a stock_quantity or price update for a product variation nothing changes. This however works 100% on a product but not a variation. The below will have no effect even though I receive an OK status 200.

PUT: wp-json/wc/v3/products/6360/variations/6361

```
{
    "stock_quantity": 7
}
```

I also tried using the batch endpoint but also nothing gets updated.

/wp-json/wc/v3/products/6360/variations/batch

```
"update": [
  {
      "id":6361,
      "stock_quantity": 4
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a bug, I was using Postman and the 200 OK returned confused the issue.

Once I added the required Content-Type:application/json header, the record successfully updated.

I also made use of a deprecated NodeJS library woocommerce-api and later tried with the replacement woocommerce-rest-api but both does not seem to handle this correctly.

I can suggest to rather just axios directly to the woocommerce rest api:

```
const baseUrl = `${process.env.WOOCOMMERCE_URI}/wp-json/wc/v3/`;
const instance = {
  headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
  auth: {
    username: process.env.WOOCOMMERCE_KEY,
    password: process.env.WOOCOMMERCE_SECRET
  }
};

let putUrl = `products/${woocommerceImport.onlineProductId}/variations/${woocommerceImport.onlineVariantId}`;

await axios.put(`${baseUrl}${putUrl}`, {
              stock_quantity: stock
            }, instance);
```